# pecl install tcpwrap error on make (centos 6.4)

Tags: php, networking, pecl, centos6

Im having hard time install tcpwrap using pecl install and also tried manual install its giving me the following error on make. I appreciate any help on how to install tcpwrap properly.

```
running: make
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootNwW6Vg/tcpwrap-1.1.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootNwW6Vg/tcpwrap-1.1.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootNwW6Vg/tcpwrap-1.1.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap/tcpwrap.c -o tcpwrap.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootNwW6Vg/tcpwrap-1.1.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootNwW6Vg/tcpwrap-1.1.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap/tcpwrap.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/tcpwrap.o
/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap/tcpwrap.c:42: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âtcpwrap_functionsâ
/root/tmp/pear/tcpwrap/tcpwrap.c:55: error: âtcpwrap_functionsâ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [tcpwrap.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```